# Using Onchange to Lookup Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a javascript file that has a drop-down list that you select a fruit out of thus grabbing an image of said fruit and then displaying the price as well. I'm getting an error on my html and I don't know what I could be doing wrong. The script isn't running... I edited out the beginning script that added a javascript drop-down list to select as it was a private link.

HTML:

```
<script src='* Link of table that provides variable urlBase, array ImageName, & an array containing price'></script>
<br>
<br>
<img id='product image' src='' height='200'>
<br>
<br> PRICE <span id='price display'></span>
<!-- Interface objects go here. -->
<!-- Insert JavaScript here. -->
<script src='js/javascript 10.js'></script>
```

and then here's my javascript....

```
document.getElementById('productID').onchange = function() {
  var productID = this.value;
  productID = parseInt(productID);
  iName = imageName[productID];
  url = urlBase + iName;
  document.getElementById('product image').src = url;
  iPrice = price[productID];
  document.getElementById('price display').innerHTML = iPrice;
};
```

Any ideas? Thank you for any help!

This is the error that I'm receiving that I don't understand as well:

```
DEBUG TRACE OF OPERATIONS - THESE OPERATIONS WERE ATTEMPTED
1. Check load of home page: javascript 10.html
2. In javascript 10.html:
    Perform: document.getElementById("productID").selectedIndex=0;
    Perform: document.getElementById("productID").selectedIndex=3;
    Perform: document.getElementById('productID').onchange();
    Check: document.getElementById('product image').src;
    Check: document.getElementById('price display').innerHTML;
    Perform: document.getElementById("productID").selectedIndex=1;
    Perform: document.getElementById('productID').onchange();
    Check: document.getElementById('product image').src;
    Check: document.getElementById('price display').innerHTML;
If you do not see your PART 2 grade then your code has an error on javascript 10.html or on the next page after javascript 10.html.
```

Comment: What kind of error is that? Are you using phonegap or something?

Comment: It's my class grader

Comment: Im not sure what that means, *my class grader*. Also, I understand you not wanting to post the url to your other page here, but you should show us the generated html and the arrays or better yet make a jsFiddle with them. Kind of tying our hands behind our backs to only  give us a fraction of the code and no way to test it...